# Execute .sql file for importing data on a Windows system with OrientDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orientdb

Hi so I have this example working:

```
DECLARE INTENT massiveinsert

CREATE CLASS POST EXTENDS V
CREATE CLASS COMMENT EXTENDS V

INSERT INTO POST (id, title) VALUES ( 10, 'NoSQL movement' );
INSERT INTO POST (id, title) VALUES ( 20, 'New OrientDB' );

INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES ( 0, 10, 'First' );
INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES ( 1, 10, 'Second' );
INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES ( 21, 10, 'Another' );
INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES ( 41, 20, 'First again' );
INSERT INTO COMMENT (id, postId, text) VALUES ( 82, 20, 'Second Again' );

CREATE edge hascomment FROM (select FROM POST) TO (select FROM COMMENT) where comment.postId=post.id
    CREATE LINK comments TYPE linkset FROM comment.postId To post.id INVERSE
UPDATE comment REMOVE postId
```

But yeah these are 7 test entries. I wanted more, so I generated some and stored it in a file. So now I wanted to execute that file:

```
IMPORT DATABASE POST.sql -merge=true
```

But that just gives me:

```
orientdb {Test2}> import database POST.sql -merge=true

Importing database POST.sql -merge=true... Started import of database
'remote:127.0.0.1/Test2' from POST.sql... Rebuild of stale indexes...
Start rebuild index ouser.name Rebuild  of index ouser.name is
completed. Start rebuild index orole.name Rebuild  of index orole.name
is completed. Stale indexes were rebuilt... Deleting RID Mapping
table...OK
```

None of the 10.000 entries were created =(

So my question is how can I execute an external sql file? And why does the import not work. Is import meant that a OrientDB file export is meant? Btw in that file are just "Insert Into .." and if a copy paste a line of them into the console, it works.

On Linux it would work with "$ console.sh database.sql" (see https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Import-RDBMS-to-Document-Model) but how to do that on Windows?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Well I now saw that it can only be exported OrientDBs being imported. Ohh man that's really senseless =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in Windows is:

1. Go to bin folder
2. Open Console here
3. Put also a test.sql here with e.g.:

   connect remote:127.0.0.1/Test root root

   CREATE CLASS POST EXTENDS V

   CREATE CLASS COMMENT EXTENDS V

   insert into POST (name_id, text) values (83, 'tellus semper interdum mauris ullamcorper purus sit amet nulla quisque arcu libero rutrum ac lobortis vel dapibus at diam nam');
4. Now write in console: console.bat test.sql

That's it. Some how it didn't work at my first try...